# What is the difference between subtyping and subsumption?

Tags: type-theory, subtyping

What is the difference between subtyping and subsumption? Does subsumption mean implicit coercion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're mostly right.

Subtyping is a relation over two *types*. By itself, it doesn't say how this relation actually applies to the typing of expressions.

Subsumption usually means the presence of a typing rule for *expressions* that allows to apply subtyping to their types implicitly. There are languages that have subtyping but no subsumption rule, and where it must be invoked explicitly with a special type annotation (e.g., OCaml).

There's also the somewhat independent aspect of whether [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) is "coercive". Coercive subtyping changes the value it is applied to. For example, in a language where `Int <: Float`, subtyping may be coercive, because ints and floats are different domains. Typical OO-style subtyping on objects usually is non-coercive. However, this is a somewhat fuzzy notion, since it often depends on the choice of semantic model, and may not necessarily make an observable difference (unless a language allows to reverse subtying with downcasts). In practice, it refers to implementation techniques more than semantics.